# sorting array of nested NSDictionary containing an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Im quite new to iOS and objective.. heres my question..
if my array looks like this:

```
myArray = {
  parentdict = {
    childdict = {
      aname = "Aname";
      bname - "Bname";
      cname = "Cname";
    };
    childarray = {
      {
        counter = "1";
        close = "25236";
      },
      {
        counter = "2";
        close = "12458";
      };
    };
  };
},
{
  parentdict = {
    childdict = {
      aname = "Aname";
      bname - "Bname";
      cname = "Cname";
    };
    childarray = {
      {
        counter = "1";
        close = "28556";
      },
      {
        counter = "2";
        close = "12118";
      };
    };
  };
},    
{
  parentdict = {
    childdict = {
      aname = "Aname";
      bname - "Bname";
      cname = "Cname";
    };
    childarray = {
      {
        counter = "1";
        close = "24356";
      },
      {
        counter = "2";
        close = "155628";
      };
    };
  };
};
```

basically its an array of nested dictionary and inside one of the dictionary contains an array of dictionary (childarray) if i want to sort myArray by @"close" of array index 1, which is the one next to counter 2, exactly how should i do this?..(perhaps i should use NSSortDescriptor?)
thanks for the reply

Comment: I'd probably just use `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have presented your structure in the *JSON* format. I assume it is for sake of presenting it to the audience here. If you are actually starting with JSON string, you will have to convert it to nested `NSArray`ies and `NSDictionary`ies using some third-party libs or iOS 5 built-in classes..

Assuming you already have your top level `NSArray* myArray`, give it a try to the following code:

```
NSArray* myArray = // ... this is your array
NSArray* sorted_array = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDictionary* left = obj1;
    NSDictionary* right = obj2;
    NSDictionary* left_parent_dict = [left objectForKey: @"parentdict"];
    NSDictionary* right_parent_dict = [right objectForKey: @"parentdict"];
    NSArray* left_child_array = [left_parent_dict objectForKey: @"childarray"];
    NSArray* right_child_array = [right_parent_dict objectForKey: @"childarray"];
    NSDictionary* left_child_first = [left_child_array objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSDictionary* right_child_first = [right_child_array objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSString* left_close = [left_child_first objectForKey: @"close"];
    NSString* right_close = [right_child_first objectForKey: @"close"];
    NSNumber* left_val = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [left_close intValue]];
    NSNumber* right_val = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [right_close intValue]];

    return [left_val compare: right_val];        
} ];
```

You will need, of course, to add some checks which I omitted for simplicity.

If you want to get descending order modify the last statement to:

```
return [right_val compare: left_val];
```

I would also suggest you considering SQL database for complex data structures as pointed out by Niko.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply...
i presented the array based on how the NSLog() presented...
`NSDictionary* right_parent_dict = [left objectForKey: @"parentdict"];
shouldn't it be the
'NSDictionary right_parent_dict = [right objectForKey:@"parentdict"];

this function returns an array of ascending data.. if i wanted in descending order how should i do this?..
if i use NSSortDescriptor is it hard?

Comment: yes, you are right, it was a copy-paste error. I have edited my answer, also to point you to how to obtain descending order. Of course, you could also use NSSortDescriptor. Should not be difficult.

Comment: tnx for the reply.. 
last question its about this kvc things.. 
i can access using
`NSDictionary *thedictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];  `[[[thedictionary objectForKey:@"parentdict"] objectForKey:@"childdict"] objectForKey:@"cname"];//"Cname"  can i still access this using valueForKeyPath:?
like  `[thedictionary valueFoKeyPath:@"parentdict.childdict.cname"];

i cant test the code today since i dont have the mac to use now..
because in sortdescriptors it uses initWithKey: which is the keyPath.. i think.. thanks again :)

Comment: Yes. You can use `valueForKeyPath`. `NSDictionary` implements `NSKeyValueCoding` to match the keys in dictionary. However, KeyPaths do not support indexing, so in the example code you could use it simplify "parentdict.childarray" only. 
Please, up-vote and accept my answer if you like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array can be quite complex, especially when the array contains nested objects. May be you should create an SQLite database

Answer (score 0):

You should use iOS 5.0's built in JSON API. [Here's a link to a great tutorial.] (http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5). JSON is really easy to work with. And that site also has great tutorials on Core Data (iOS's SQLite API) [here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) There are two more parts to that tutorial as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[array sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){
    int firstValue = [[obj1 objectForKey:@"someKey"] intValue];
    int secondValue = [[obj2 objectForKey:@"someKey"] intValue];
    int valueDiff = firstValue - secondValue;
    return (valueDiff == 0) ? NSOrderedSame : (valueDiff < 0) ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

Comment: It does not answer the original question.